# how to add a view in front of a Texview and start the next line from the added view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

[image]

trying to achieve this

I tried using spannable string and ImageSpan but I need functionality to change text also in the view

Comment: Why do you need the `ImageSpan`? Is it just for that vertical bar? If so, couldn't you achieve that design with one `SpannableString` that has color and size/style spans for the beginning letters ("Ad"), then the `ImageSpan` for the vertical bar, then the rest of the text?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MikeM. issue here is to give margin around that vertical bar

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, exactly, but it's probably going to be much easier to create a custom `ImageSpan`, rather than trying to line up two `TextView`s and their texts like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kotlin Jetpack Compose you can use row, there will be image and text in the row and you can shape them according to you and add a vertical divider in between.

**For example:**

```
  Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp),
        horizontalArrangement =Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
    ){

       Image(painter = R.drawable.x, contentDescription ="image description" )

        Divider(
            color = Color.Gray,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()  //fill the max height
                .width(1.dp)
        )
        Text("text example ")
    }
```